# Parralelized code runs much slower in Python than in Matlab

Tags: python, matlab, python-2.7, numpy, multiprocessing

I have a piece of code that does the following:

```
for each file (already read in the RAM):
    call a function and obtain a result
add the results up and disply
```

Each file can be analyzed in parallel. The function that analyzes each file is as following:

```
# Complexity = 1000*19*19 units of work
def fun(args):
    (a, b, p) = args
    for itr in range(1000):
        for i in range(19):
            for j in range(19):
                # The following random number generated depends on
                # latest values in (i-1, j), (i+1, j), (i, j-1) & (i, j+1)
                # cells of latest a and b arrays
                u = np.random.rand();
                if (u < p):
                    a[i, j] += -1
                else:
                    b[i, j] += 1
    return a+b
```

I am using `multiprocessing` package to achieve parallelism:

```
import numpy as np
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = time.time()
    pool = Pool(processes=cpu_count())
    args = [None]*100
    for i in range(100):
        a = np.random.randint(2, size=(19, 19))
        b = np.random.randint(2, size=(19, 19))
        p = np.random.rand()
        args[i] = (a, b, p)
    result = pool.map(fun, args)
    for i in range(2, 100):
        result[0] += result[i]
    print result[0]
    print time.time() - t
```

I have written equivalent `MATLAB` code that uses `parfor` and calls `fun` in each iteration of `parfor`:

```
tic
args = cell(100, 1);
r = cell(100, 1);
parfor i = 1:100
   a = randi(2, 19, 19);
   b = randi(2, 19, 19);
   p = rand();
   args{i}.a = a;
   args{i}.b = b;
   args{i}.p = p;
   r{i} = fun(args{i});
end

for i = 2:100
    r{1} = r{1} + r{i};
end
disp(r{1});
toc
```

The implementation of `fun` is as follows:

```
function [ ret ] = fun( args )
a = args.a;
b = args.b;
p = args.p;

for itr = 1:1000
    for i = 1:19
        for j = 1:19
            u = rand();
            if (u < p)
                a(i, j) = a(i, j) + -1;
            else
                b(i, j) = b(i, j) + 1;
            end
        end
    end
end
ret = a + b;
end
```

I find that `MATLAB` is blazingly fast, it takes around 1.5 seconds on a dual core processor compared to around 33-34 seconds taken by `Python` program. Why is this so?

EDIT: A lot of answers suggested that I should vectorize the random number generation. Actually the way it works is, random number generated depends on the latest a and b 2D arrays. I just put a simple `rand()` call to keep program simple and readable. In actuality of my program, random number is always generated by looking at certain horizontally and vertically neighbouring cells of (i, j) cell. So it is not possible to vectorize that.

Answer (score 2):

Have you benchmarked both implementations of `fun` in a non-parallel context? One might just be a lot faster. In particular, those nested loops in the Python `fun` look like they might turn in to a faster vectorized solution in Matlab, or may be optimized by Matlab's JIT.

Stick both implementations in profilers to see where they're spending their time. Convert both implementations to non-parallel and profile those first, to make sure they're equivalent in performance before introducing the complexities of the parallelization stuff.

And one last check - you're setting up Matlab's Parallel Computation Toolbox with a local pool of workers, right, and not hooking in to a remote machine or picking up some other resources? How many workers on the Matlab side?

Comment: I have added `MATLAB` implementation.

Comment: I have made an edit to the original question at the bottom. It explains that it is not possible to vectorize the random number generation. Also, I tried generating p values in parallel, it had no effect on the running time of the `Python` version.

Comment: Gotcha. Removing the stuff about random numbers in my answer. It might help if you could include the actual calculation it's doing - the performance difference may well depend on the kind of operations it's doing. Calling a PRNG isn't necessarily a great proxy for it. E.g. simple math on local numeric arrays may be optimized well by Matlab's JIT. (And may well be vectorizable too.)

Answer (score 1):

I did some tests on your Python code, though without the `multiprocessing` part and achieved a roughly 25x speedup by making the following changes:

- Used Python lists instead of a NumPy array, because the latter is really slow when you need to do a lot of indexing. My timings are including the time it takes to do `ndarray.tolist()` so this might actually be a viable option, as long as the array's are not to big I think.
- Ran it in PyPy instead of the regular Python interpreter, because PyPy has a JIT-compiler, to make the comparison with MATLAB a bit more fair. Regular CPython doesn't have such a feature.
- Made the "random" call local to the function, i.e. do `rand = np.random.rand` and later `u = rand()`, because in Python lookups in the local namespace are faster, which can be significant in tight loops such as this.
- Used Python's `random.random` instead of `np.random.rand` (also bound to a name local to the function).
- Exchanged `range` for the generator-based `xrange`.

*(This list is sorted from most significant speedup to only very small gain)*

Of course there's also the parallel computing aspect. With `multiprocessing` all the Python objects that are passed around between processes are "pickled", meaning they have to be serialized and de-serialized on top of being copied between processes. MATLAB also copies data between processes (or threads?), but probably does so in a less wasteful way. Next to that, setting up a `multiprocessing.Pool` also takes a short while, which may not be fair to your MATLAB benchmark, but I'm not sure about this.

Based on your timings and mine, I would say that Python and MATLAB could be about equally fast for this specific task. But, unfortunately you have to jump through some hoops to get that speed with Python. Maybe using the `@autojit` capability of Numba could be interesting in this regard, if you have that available.

Answer (score 0):

Given the available information, you would probably benefit from using Cython, which let's you also use some [parallelism](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/parallelism.html). Depending on the random numbers you need you could for instance use GSL to generate them.

### Original question

There's no need to use `multiprocessing`, because `fun` can be easily vectorized, which yields a massive speed up (over 50x).

I'm not sure why matlab is not hit so hard as numpy, but its JIT may be saving it. Python does not like doing two `.` look ups in the inner loop, nor calling expensive functions there.

```
def fun_fast(args):
     a, b, p = args
     for i in xrange(19):
         for j in xrange(19):
             u = np.random.rand(1000)
             msk = u < p
             msk_sum = msk.sum()
             a[i, j] -= msk_sum
             b[i, j] += msk.size - msk_sum
     return a + b
```

Comment: I have made an edit to the original question at the bottom. It explains that it is not possible to vectorize the random number generation. Please take that into account.

Comment: @abhinavkulkarni I'm afraid that completely changes your question because that random part is the key part.

Answer (score 0):

Try this version of fun and see if it gives you a speedup.

```
def fun(args):
    a, b, p = args
    n = 1000
    u = np.random.random((n, 19, 19))
    msk = u < p
    msk_sum = msk.sum(0)
    a -= msk_sum
    b += (n - msk_sum)

    return a + b
```

This is the more efficient way of implement this kind of function using numpy.

These kinds of nested loops can have quite high overhead in interpreted languages like matlab and python, but I suspect the JIT is compensating, at least partially, in matlab so the performance difference between the vectorized and loop implementations will be smaller. Cpython does not currently have any optimizations for these kinds of loops (that I know of) but but at least one python implementation, [pypy](http://pypy.org/), does have a JIT. Unfortunately pypy currently only has limited numpy support.

Update:

It seems like you have an iterative algorithm, and at least in my experience, those are the hardest to optimize with numpy/cpython. Consider using [cython](http://www.cython.org/), this [tutorial](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/numpy.html) might also be useful, to write your nested loops. Other people might have other suggestions, but that's the best I can think of.

Comment: I have made an edit to the original question at the bottom. It explains that it is not possible to vectorize the random number generation. Please take that into account.